# Could not determine access type for property "attribute"

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I made a form so that I can fill my database without using phpmyadmin. But now I am having an issue when I try to execute the form and hope that you guys can help me. I recieve the following error:

> Could not determine access type for property "bestelserie" in class "AppBundle\Entity\Artikel".

My code:

Default controller:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use AppBundle\Entity\Artikel;
use AppBundle\Form\Type\ArtikelType;


class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        ]);
    }

    /** 
    * @Route ("/artikel/nieuw ", name="artikelnieuw")
    */
    public function nieuweArtikel(Request $request){
        $nieuweArtikel = new Artikel();
        $form = $this->createForm(ArtikelType::class, $nieuweArtikel);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($nieuweArtikel);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateurl("artikelnieuw"));
        }

        return new Response($this->render('form.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView())));
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Artikel
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="artikel")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Artikel
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="artikelnummer", type="string", length=20, unique=true)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $artikelnummer;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="omschrijving", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $omschrijving;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="specificaties", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $specificaties;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="inkoopprijs", type="string", length = 255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $magazijnlocatie;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="inkoopprijs", type="20", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $inkoopprijs;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="vervangendeArtikel", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $vervangendeArtikel;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="minimumVoorraad", type="integer", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $minimumVoorraad;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="voorraadaantal", type="integer", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $voorraadaantal;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="bestelserie", type="integer", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $bestelserie;


    /**
     * Set artikelnummer
     *
     * @param string $artikelnummer
     *
     * @return Artikel
     */
    public function setArtikelnummer($artikelnummer)
    {
        $this->artikelnummer = $artikelnummer;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get artikelnummer
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getArtikelnummer()
    {
        return $this->artikelnummer;
    }

    /**
     * Set omschrijving
     *
     * @param string $omschrijving
     *
     * @return Artikel
     */
    public function setOmschrijving($omschrijving)
    {
        $this->omschrijving = $omschrijving;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get omschrijving
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOmschrijving()
    {
        return $this->omschrijving;
    }

    /**
     * Set specificaties
     *
     * @param string $specificaties
     *
     * @return Artikel
     */
    public function setSpecificaties($specificaties)
    {
        $this->specificaties = $specificaties;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get specificaties
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSpecificaties()
    {
        return $this->specificaties;
    }

    /**
     * Set magazijnlocatie
     *
     * @param string $magazijnlocatie
     *
     * @return Artikel
     */
    public function setMagazijnlocatie($magazijnlocatie)
    {
        $this->magazijnlocatie = $magazijnlocatie;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get magazijnlocatie
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMagazijnlocatie()
    {
        return $this->magazijnlocatie;
    }

    /**
     * Set inkoopprijs
     *
     * @param integer $inkoopprijs
     *
     * @return Artikel
     */
    public function setInkoopprijs($inkoopprijs)
    {
        $this->inkoopprijs = $inkoopprijs;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get inkoopprijs
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getInkoopprijs()
    {
        return $this->inkoopprijs;
    }

    /**
     * Set vervangendeArtikel
     *
     * @param string $vervangendeArtikel
     *
     * @return Artikel
     */
    public function setVervangendeartikel($vervangendeArtikel)
    {
        $this->vervangendeArtikel = $vervangendeArtikel;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get vervangendeArtikel
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getVervangendeartikel()
    {
        return $this->vervangendeArtikel;
    }

     /**
     * Set minimumVoorraad
     *
     * @param integer $minimumVoorraad
     *
     * @return Artikel
     */
    public function setMinimumvoorraad($minimumVoorraad)
    {
        $this->minimumVoorraad = $minimumVoorraad;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get minimumVoorraad
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getMinimumvoorraad()
    {
        return $this->minimumVoorraad;
    }

     /**
     * Set voorraadaantal
     *
     * @param integer $voorraadaantal
     *
     * @return Artikel
     */
    public function setVoorraadaantal($voorraadaantal)
    {
        $this->voorraadaantal = $voorraadaantal;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get voorraadaantal
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getVoorraadaantal()
    {
        return $this->voorraadaantal;
    }

     /**
     * Set bestelserie
     *
     * @param integer $bestelserie
     *
     * @return Artikel
     */
    public function setBestelserie()
    {
        if ($this->minimumVoorraad > $this->voorraadaantal){
            $benodigdeVoorraad = $this->minimumVoorraad - $this->voorraadaantal;
            return $this->bestelserie + $benodigdeVoorraad;
        }
        else {
            return $this->bestelserie;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get bestelserie
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getBestelserie()
    {
        return $this->bestelserie;
    }
}
```

Form:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

//vul aan als je andere invoerveld-typen wilt gebruiken in je formulier
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

//EntiteitType vervangen door b.v. KlantType
class ArtikelType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        //gebruiken wat je nodig hebt, de id hoeft er niet bij als deze auto increment is
        $builder
            ->add('artikelnummer', TextType::class) //naam is b.v. een attribuut of variabele van klant
        ;
        $builder
            ->add('omschrijving', TextType::class) //naam is b.v. een attribuut of variabele van klant
        ;
        $builder
            ->add('specificaties', TextType::class) //naam is b.v. een attribuut of variabele van klant
        ;
        $builder
            ->add('magazijnlocatie', TextType::class) //naam is b.v. een attribuut of variabele van klant
        ;
        $builder
            ->add('inkoopprijs', IntegerType::class) //naam is b.v. een attribuut of variabele van klant
        ;
        $builder
            ->add('vervangendeArtikel', TextType::class) //naam is b.v. een attribuut of variabele van klant
        ;
        $builder
            ->add('minimumVoorraad', IntegerType::class) //naam is b.v. een attribuut of variabele van klant
        ;
        $builder
            ->add('voorraadaantal', IntegerType::class) //naam is b.v. een attribuut of variabele van klant
        ;
        $builder
            ->add('bestelserie', IntegerType::class) //naam is b.v. een attribuut of variabele van klant
        ;



        //zie
        //http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#built-in-field-types
        //voor meer typen invoer
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Artikel', //Entiteit vervangen door b.v. Klant
        ));
    }
}

?>
```

[image: Database table]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add the full error stack trace in your question so we can see what code throws this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be your setter declaration for `bestelserie` property. In fact your function doesn't accept any argument

```
public function setBestelserie()
{
    ...
}
```

while setter function is supposed to accept an argument and set it as property value

```
public function setBestelserie($bestelserie)
{
    ...
    $this->bestelserie = $bestelserie;
}
```

otherwise your form is unable to set a value for it.